# conversion of simple volume to primary volume

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, gparted, diskpart, partition-magic

My Samsung laptop has 5 partition in it . And all are  simple volume partition so that there is no primary partition in my disk hence i cannot install Ubuntu in my laptop .I have tried many software for conversion of simple volume to primary volume but none of them work for my satisfaction so i look forward for an positive reply.

```
LOCAL DISK (C:\)   simple volume
M          (D:\)   simple volume
EDU        (E:\)   simple volume 
SoFT       (F:\)   simple volume
STUFF      (I:\)   simple volume
```

> I want to convert my disk into following type

```
LOCAL DISK (C:\)   Primary volume
M          (D:\)   Primary volume
EDU        (E:\)   Primary volume 
SoFT       (F:\)   Logical volume
STUFF      (I:\)   Logical volume
```

Comment: I don't know what Simple means but I don't think it gets in your way. I have a partition that disk management calls "simple" that is Primary.  I suggest you include a screenshot of what disk management shows you. I also suggest you run easeus and see what it tells you about whether you partitions are primary or logical or extended.

Comment: Also, your terminology may be wrong. Volume may refer to the file system within the partition.  So primary or logical refer to the partition not to the volume. For the record, my laptop has C: Layout:simple Type:basic  primary partition.

Comment: @barlop mine has C: Layout:simple Type:dynamic all drive have same structure

Comment: What does Easeus and paragon say(download it)?  (paragon partition manager and easeus partition mater).  I don't know if it's risky to change dynamic to basic, or if it's something you'd want to do but here is an article on it  "Change a Dynamic Disk Back to a Basic Disk".     http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238.aspx  And here is one on basic and dynamic disks "Basic and Dynamic Disks"  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Linux may have a problem seeing windows's dynamic disks here's an article about ubuntu specifically and how to http://www.rodneybeede.com/Mount_Windows_dynamic_disks__spanned__in_Linux.html